# Python Export Excel Sheet Range as Image in linux environment

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Is there any package for saving excel sheet as an image in Linux environment?
the way we do in windows using win32.

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import  time
cwd=os.getcwd()
workbook_file_name = path
excel=Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook_file_name)
selection = "A1:L30"
xl_range = wb.Sheets("Summary Report").Range(selection)
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After=excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)).Name="image_sheet"
cht = excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects().Add(0,0,xl_range.Width, xl_range.Height)
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
xl_range.CopyPicture()
    # add the chart to new sheet
time.sleep(1)
cht.Chart.Paste()
    # Export the sheet with the chart to a new file
time.sleep(1)
cht.Chart.Export(cwd+"/../../abc.jpg")
    # Delete the sheet
cht.Delete()
excel.ActiveSheet.Delete()
    # Close the book
```

Comment: Hi Anil, wondering if you have found a solution to this. I'm facing the same challenge, excel2img doesn't work in Linux.